# Como parar de observar as mudanças de um determinado arquivo?

Tags: git

O cenário é o seguinte. Eu trabalho em um projeto que contém um arquivo JSON com a configuração do banco de dados. Algo como:

```
{
    "db_config": 
     {
        "conn_string": "server:localhost;user:db-user;password=db-pass"
     }
}
```

Acontece que eu preciso alterar estas configurações para rodar o projeto no meu ambiente local, isto porque uso o banco remoto, em um servidor local.

O problema é que sempre que eu altero este arquivo com as minhas configurações

1. Preciso lembrar de não adicioná-lo antes do *commit*; ou
2. Preciso lembrar de alterá-lo antes de *commit*; ou
3. Acabo *commitando* o arquivo e "estragando" a configuração de todos os meus colegas de projeto.

Colocar o arquivo no *.gitignore* faria com que ele fosse excluído do repositório remoto.

Como posso fazer para pedir pro GIT ignorar todas as mudanças que eu fizer neste arquivo? E como posso reverter isto caso necessite mudar alguma configuração neste arquivo posteriormente?

Comment: O que costumo fazer é fazer um commit com o ficheiro vazio e depois colocar no `.gitignore`. Depois, em produção, as variáveis ou são colocadas em `env` ou esse ficheiro é sobreposto no servidor por outro com as chaves completas.

Comment: Sugiro trabalhar com profiles, um para dev e outro para prod. Cada um terá sua configuração e não precisará alterá-los mais.

Comment: Agradeço as dicas, mas eu quero só um comando do GIT pra parar de "observar mudanças" em um determinado arquivo. O cenário é fictício =D

Comment: @jbueno entendi sua necessidade, você só quer evitar modificações em um determinado arquivo de configuração, mas ele precisa existir previamente de qualquer forma, veja se isto resolve http://stackoverflow.com/a/21756612/1518921

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [assume-unchanged](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#git-update-index---no-assume-unchanged) para isso.

Ficaria algo parecido com isso:

> git update-index --assume-unchanged path/file

E para voltar a "obervar", basta fazer isso:

> git update-index --no-assume-unchanged path/file