# Trabalhando com dois "remotes" diferentes com o git

Tags: git, github

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para excluir os dados sensíveis (senhas e etc) do commit de um repositório remoto, mas mantendo em outro? Explico:

Tenho um repositório no Github e outro no Heroku, meu projeto está apontando para os dois repositórios. Na hora de subir no heroku eu preciso deixar os dados sensíveis como senha de banco de dados, AWS e etc. No Github essas informações não devem subir, mas quando eu dou um "git add ." e depois um "git commit -m..." esse commit fica no stage, eu consigo enviar ele para o Heroku somente dando um "git push heroku", mas quando eu preciso alterar algo no projeto e enviar dessa vez para o github as informações sensíveis vão ficar visíveis nesse penúltimo commit, ficou confuso, mas ficou claro rs?

Obs: não se trata de deixar de observar o arquivo, mas excluir um commit do stage (o que contém os dados sensíveis), mantendo as demais alterações do último commit.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como parar de observar as mudanças de um determinado arquivo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193951/como-parar-de-observar-as-mudan%c3%a7as-de-um-determinado-arquivo)

Comment: não se trata de deixar de observar o arquivo, mas excluir um commit do stage (o que contém os dados sensíveis), mantendo as demais alterações do último commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git e sistemas de versionamento em geral **não devem guardar dados sensíveis como senhas e credenciais**, mesmo em repositórios privados. Isso é justamente porque uma vez no histórico esse tipo de problema se torna comum.

A solução que a própria Heroku recomenda é guardar esses dados em variáveis de ambiente e no seu código você apenas acessa os dados. Assim eles nunca ficam no histórico e você não corre o risco de mandar por acidente para um repositório público.

[Documentação e exemplos aqui](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)