# Como atualizar todos arquivos de um repositório GIT, exceto um específico?

Tags: git

Utilizando o git, é possível criar o arquivo `.gitignore`, para não realizar o envio de arquivos específicos, durante o `git push origin`. Gostaria de realizar o inverso, carregar todos os arquivos exceto um arquivo em específico.

Verifiquei a documentação do [git-pull](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/pt_BR), no entanto, não encontrei nada relacionado.

Como atualizar `git pull origin` todos arquivos de um repositório git, exceto um arquivo específico?

Comment: A última frase não bateu com o resto da pergunta. Você quer ignorar uma pasta exceto um arquivo?

Comment: Com "carregar" vc quer dizer baixar, tipo durante um *git clone*?

Comment: Quando me refiro a carregar, me refiro a atualizar um repositório `git pull origin`, no entanto há arquivos que eu não gostaria de atualizar.

Comment: Veja se é isso que você quer https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/193951/como-parar-de-observar-as-mudan%c3%a7as-de-um-determinado-arquivo/193957#193957

Comment: Acredito que não tenha como fazer isso em um só comando. Um _workaround_ seria:
1. git stash -- seu_arquivo    # coloca seu arquivo em uma fila
2. git pull   # baixa tudo
3. git stash pop   # retorna seu arquivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer o `git pull origin <branch>` sem alterar algum arquivo modificado em seu repositório local, você pode realizar os seguintes passos:

1. Salvar os arquivos alterados em uma fila: `git stash`
2. Baixar os arquivos do repositório: `git pull origin <branch>`
3. Retornar seus arquivos: `git stash pop`

Observação: Arquivos que foram alterados tanto remotamente, quanto localmente será necessário realizar `merge`, caso queira manter o arquivo alterado em sua máquina sem realizar o `merge`, basta deletá-los antes de realizar a etapa 3.

Mais informações sobre o [git-stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).